# How to set a property null on any kind of error in a project

Tags: c#, dll, null

I have a c# class project and there is a public property that you can access it from anywhere. Also i have a lot of methods in this project. I just want to set this property's value to null when an error raised in any methods. Is there any way for it? I don't want to write try catch block for all methods. I just want something's like trigger to run after any kind of error in project to set this property's value null.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking here, please be more explicit.

Comment: I updated my question. hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException+=delegate(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)){
   theProperty=null;
};
```

this works only for .Net 4 +

for .Net 2+ you can use Application.ThreadException

Comment: Where shall i write it? I don't have form_load event in class project

Comment: add Function name it Init, use the code there , and force any one who wants your classLibrary to call it at there app start.

Comment: or you can use it in any static constructor in any of your class library class, static constructor will be executed whenever that class is loaded.

Comment: Thanks. static constructors are what i really needed. Thanks again bro.